# HadoopFileSystem : getUsed

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to use the `getUsed()` function in the `FileSystem` class :

```
Configuration l_configuration = new Configuration();

l_configuration.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9100");
l_configuration.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:9101");
l_configuration.setBoolean("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", true);

FileSystem l_fileSystem = FileSystem.get(l_configuration);

long size = 0;
size = l_fileSystem.getUsed();

System.out.println("Total size : "+size); // Total size : 0
```

But I'm sure to have some files in my HDFS. If I execute the following command shell :

```
$ hadoop dfs -dus
hdfs://localhost:9100/user/xxx/yyy  358873405
```

How to use the `getUsed()` function ?

Comment: And if you use `hadoop dfs -ls /` do you see files ?

Comment: I see 2 folders : cygdrive and user. Maybe should I precise I am on Cygwin

Comment: and `hadoop dfs -ls` : I see all my folders I have to size

Comment: Awesome question indeed!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getUsed() function :

```
public long getUsed(){      

    long l_used = 0;
    FileStatus[] files = m_fileSystem.listStatus(new Path("/"));
    for (FileStatus file : files)
        l_used += file.getLen();

    return l_used;

}
```

I think Cygwin installation doens't support the Path "/". So I rewrote the function :

```
public long sizePath(String a_path) throws IOException{     

    long l_used = 0;
    FileStatus[] files = m_fileSystem.listStatus(new Path(a_path));
    for (FileStatus file : files)
        l_used += file.getLen();

    return l_used;

}
```

And I can size a specific folder in HDFS.

Comment: Featuring cygwin more prominently in your question would have been the way to go here. ;)

Comment: Which distribution of Hadoop are you using By the Way?

Comment: I think Cygwin support "/", can you confirm?

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 0.20.2 (the only distribution working with my windows installation). Cygwin supports "/" in most of cases but not with my hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider DistributedFileSystem not FileSystem to get the size correctly.

Replace the following with,

```
FileSystem l_fileSystem = FileSystem.get(l_configuration);

long size = 0;
size = l_fileSystem.getUsed();
```

with this,

```
DistributedFileSystem l_fileSystem = (DistributedFileSystem) DistributedFileSystem.get(l_configuration);

long size = 0;
size = l_fileSystem.getDiskStatus().getUsed();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my HDFS is on a single node ! I answered my question

Comment: Are you not using HDFS?

Comment: I'm using it, on single node

Comment: So, you can probably use that on a single node too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your code like following :

```
Configuration l_configuration = new Configuration();

l_configuration.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9100");
l_configuration.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:9101");
l_configuration.setBoolean("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", true);
try{
    FileSystem l_fileSystem = FileSystem.get(l_configuration);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}

long size = 0;
size = l_fileSystem.getUsed();

System.out.println("Total size : "+size); // Total size : 0
```

After reading documentation I do not see any other reason than an exception at FileSystem initialization.